# Problema al usar una variable de sesion de php codeigniter en un archivo js

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-3

como bien lo coloque en la pregunta, ¿como puedo hacer para usar una variable de sesion de codeigniter a un archivo js?

ahora bien, hay ciertas cosas que se debe saber;

Lo primero es: Las variables de sesion estan en un archivo Y donde las quiero usar es otro archivo (.js).

Lo Segundo es: Que estoy trabajando el html y el Js en un mismo Archivo.

y Lo Tercero es: Que estoy organizando mi codigo y estoy colocando los archivos php, html, js c/u donde corresponde, es decir, los js en su carpeta de js, los html en su carpeta html y asi ....

y sucede que ya no me reconoce las variables de sesion de php codeigniter porque al mudar todo el Script a su archivo correspondiente, no existen en dichas variables de sesion.

En Resumen: ¿Existira Alguna Forma de usar variables de sesion php, en un archivo Js ?

-> Sabiendo que son 2 archivos diferentes.

aca les dejo el Codigo como lo tengo actualmente (todo en un mismo archivo .php):

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

var nom = "<?php print $this->session->userdata("sess_names"); ?>";
var ape = "<?php print $this->session->userdata("sess_apes"); ?>";
var ced = "<?php print $this->session->userdata("sess_cedu"); ?>";

...

</script>
```

Comment: Hola Bienvenido a StackOrverflow, te sugiero leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), realices el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ganar tu primer medalla y entiendas como funciona el sitio. Ahora conforme a tu pregunta lo que pudieramos adelantar es que no puedes incrustar código php en un archivo con otra extensión que no sea php, coloca la estructura de tus archivos para entender mejor tu problema. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una vez intente lo mismo que quieres hacer y pudieras intentar enviarlo en la URL como una especie de metodo GET, pero esto implica en lo siguiente

Debes enviar las variables en la invocación del Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/codigo.js?var1=var_sess_1;var2=var_sess_2"></script>
```

Y utilizacando el comando dentro del Script obtener la URL:

localhost/js/codigo.js?var1=valor;var2=valor

```
var URLactual = window.location.href;
alert(URLactual);
```

Y utilizando un método de parceo con la funcion **.split** y asi separar las variables indicadas despues del **?** asi asignarlas en variables internar del archivo.

Pero todo esto implica mucho trabajo y esfuerzo que aveces es dudable si vale la pena realizar.

Una segunda opción dependiendo de lo que querias hacer es utilizar **Ajax** ya que ejecutas parte de tu codigo en el Js y luego realizas la petición del lado del servidor (php) donde puedes utilizar tus variables de sesion.

Otra opción mas sencilla para estos casos es simplemente crear un archivo **.php** lo ubicas en la misma carpeta de los js y este solo contiene tus funciones de js al que le envíes tus variables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Codigo Java SCript */
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Amigo! ciertamente tendre que hacerlo de alguna de esas manera sino, lo tendre que dejar en el mismo archivo...